# Created add() method to insert objects into an array and all i get are null values

Tags: java

this is a class called Doglist to add the object to an array.

```
public class DogList {
  private int numItems;
  private DogItem[] dogListArray;
  private int position;

  DogList ()    {
    numItems=0;
    position = 0;
    dogListArray = new DogItem[10]; 
}

public void add (DogItem item)  {
    dogListArray[numItems++]= new DogItem(item.getName(), 
                                          item.getBreed(),
                                          item.getWeight(),
                                          item.getOwner1(),
                                          item.getOwner2()
                                          );
   }

public String toString()    {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<numItems; i++)  {
        result += dogListArray[i].toString() + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
  public DogItem searchForDogItem (DogItem gi)  {

    System.out.println("Here is your obj value: " + gi ); 

    return null;
}//This is the one im having trouble with.
}
```

I have all the setters and getters in the DogItem class.
and this is from the UI where i get the dog info(name, breed, weight, owners1&2 names)

```
public void searchForItem (String name )    {

    DogItem gi = new DogItem (name);

    gi = gl.searchForDogItem(gi);

    if (gi==null)   {
        msgTextField.setText("Dog Not Found");
    } else  {
        nameTextField.setText(String.valueOf(gi.getName()));
        breedTextField.setText(String.valueOf(gi.getBreed()));
        weightTextField.setText(String.valueOf(gi.getWeight())); 
        owner1TextField.setText(String.valueOf(gi.getOwner1()));
        owner2TextField.setText(String.valueOf(gi.getOwner2()));
    }
}
```

Ill try and clear things up as i go.

this is the output i get

Here is your obj value: null    null    0.0 null    null

Comment: You're leaving out a lot of code. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I was about to say the same exact thing... You have references to variables or objects that we can't see what you are doing... I have a clue but you don't have enough here to say what is wrong.

Comment: updating it now

Comment: I posted an answer below which I tried out and works.

Comment: thank you im going through it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is what it probably should look like instead. Just from what I saw wrong already. However you'd probably want to override the toString() method of DogItem.

Main method example of this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DogItem dogItem = new DogItem("Spot", "Dalmation", "45", "Bob", "Sandy");
        DogItem.add(dogItem);

        DogItem result = DogItem.searchForItem("Spot");

        if (result == null) {
            System.out.println("Dog not found");
            // GUI error output goes here
        } else {
            System.out.println("Here is your obj value: " + result);
            // Where your GUI stuff goes
        }
    }
}
```

DogItem example of this:

```
public class DogItem {
    private static DogItem[] dogListArray = new DogItem[100];
    private static int numItems = 0;

    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String weight;
    private String owner1;
    private String owner2;

    public DogItem(String name, String breed, String weight, String owner1, String owner2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.owner1 = owner1;
        this.owner2 = owner2;
    }

    public static void add(DogItem dogItem) {
        dogListArray[numItems++] = dogItem;
    }

    public static DogItem searchForItem(String name) {
        DogItem dogItem = null;
        for (DogItem result : dogListArray) {
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.getName() == name) {
                    dogItem = result;
                }
            }
        }
        return dogItem;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = name + ", " + breed + ", " + weight + ", " + owner1 + " " + owner2;
        return result;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }
    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public String getOwner1() {
        return owner1;
    }
    public void setOwner1(String owner1) {
        this.owner1 = owner1;
    }
    public String getOwner2() {
        return owner2;
    }
    public void setOwner2(String owner2) {
        this.owner2 = owner2;
    }
}
```

These would be recommended changes from me though:

```
    private static ArrayList<String> owners;
    private static ArrayList<DogItem> dogsList;
    public DogItem(String name, String breed, String weight, String owner) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.owners.add(owner);
    }
    public void init() {
        owners = new ArrayList<String>();
        dogsList = new ArrayList<DogItem>();
    }
    public void addDog(DogItem dogItem) {
        dogsList.add(dogItem);
    }
    public DogItem searchForItem(String name) {
        DogItem dogItem = null;
        for (DogItem result : dogsList) {
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.getName() == name) {
                    dogItem = result;
                }
            }
        }
        return dogItem;
    }
    public void addOwner(String owner) {
        owners.add(owner);
    }
    public String getOwner() {
        return owners.get(owners.size() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Added the error check in there in the case the dog wasn't found. Additionally note that the else statement is where you'd assign your values to the GUI that you are implementing.

Comment: Ok so i get it and your code works, but my question now is if you where to print out the "String name" in the searchForItem method without doing your checks and it prints null for all values or even better it prints out the object location..

Comment: I realized what you were talking about and fixed that. This is more or less what you are looking for.

Comment: Ya that pretty much hit the nail on the head. I knew array list would be what to use but i wanted to do it with an array to make sure i had a better understanding. of arrays and passing objects to them. Thanks for the help and insight.